# 3d array print address after deference twice?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Why does a 3D array print address after being dereferenced twice? Please help me understand the code posted below, (assume that the array begins at location 1002).

```
int main()
{
   int a[2][3][4]={
                   {
                     1,2,3,4,
                     4,5,6,7,
                     9,1,1,2
                   },
                   {
                     2,1,4,7,
                     6,7,8,9,
                     0,0,0,0
                   }
                 };

   printf("%u %u %u %u\n",a,*a,**a,***a); //a == *a == **a, all print address 1002. Why?
```

}

Comment: Because arrays in C are nothing more than a section of memory that is `x*y*z*sizeof(T)` large, with some operators for accessing values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**a` has type `int *` and points to the first `int` in the 3D array
`*a` has type `int (*)[4]` and points to the first row of the 3D array
`a` has type `int (*)[3][4]` and points to the first 2D array in the 3D array
`&a` has type `int (*)[2][3][4]` and points to the whole 3D array

So they are all pointers that point to the same address. It's just that the *type* of the pointer is different. The following code may help illustrate this point.

```
int main( void )
{
    int a[2][3][4]={ 1,2,3,4, 4,5,6,7, 9,1,1,2,    2,1,4,7, 6,7,8,9, 0,0,0,0 };

    int *ptrInt;                // pointer to an int
    int (*ptrArray1)[4];        // pointer to an array of ints
    int (*ptrArray2)[3][4];     // pointer to a 2D array of ints
    int (*ptrArray3)[2][3][4];  // pointer to a 3D array of ints

    ptrInt    = **a;
    ptrArray1 = *a;
    ptrArray2 = a;
    ptrArray3 = &a;

    printf( "%p %p\n", ptrInt   , ptrInt    + 1 );
    printf( "%p %p\n", ptrArray1, ptrArray1 + 1 );
    printf( "%p %p\n", ptrArray2, ptrArray2 + 1 );
    printf( "%p %p\n", ptrArray3, ptrArray3 + 1 );
}
```

<sub>Note: I left out the inner braces in the array initialization specifically to demonstrate that the inner braces are optional.  Best practice would have all of the inner braces.</sub>

Typical output from this code is shown below. I've added comments to show the difference between the two pointers as a decimal number.

```
0x17b00 0x17b04  //  4 bytes, hence pointer to an int
0x17b00 0x17b10  // 16 bytes, pointer to int[4]
0x17b00 0x17b30  // 48 bytes, pointer to int[3][4]
0x17b00 0x17b60  // 96 bytes, pointer to int[2][3][4]
```

Note that when you add 1 to any pointer, the size of the object is added to the pointer. For example, if you have an `int *` and you add `1` to that pointer, the value of the pointer will increase by 4 because `sizeof(int) == 4`. <sub>(Yes, that assumes that ints are 32-bits, thank you.)</sub>

So by adding 1 to a pointer, you can determine the size of the object that the pointer points to. That gives you a clue about the type of the pointer from the compiler's point of view. In the example above, notice that adding 1 to `ptrArray1` changes the pointer by 16. That's because `ptrArray1` points to an object of size 16, specifically it points to an array of 4 ints.

---

Just so that we're all completely confused, allow me to say that the following line of code will print the number `8`. I chose 8 since it only appears once in the array, so you can tell where it's coming from.

```
    printf( "%d\n", ptrArray3[0][1][1][2]);
```

Notice that it appears that I'm using `ptrArray3` as a 4-dimensional array. This is why pointers to multidimensional arrays are so confusing in C. When you convert an array to a pointer, the pointer has one less dimension than the array. But when you use the pointer with array syntax, you use it as though it had one more dimension.

So for example, start with a 2D array

```
int array[4][100];
```

The corresponding pointer is a pointer to a 1D array

```
int (*ptr)[100] = array;
```

But you can use that pointer like a 2D array

```
ptr[2][100] = 6;
```

That is the basis for all of the confusion, and the reason that pointer-to-array is a seldom used feature in C.

Answer (score 1):

`a` has the type `array of size 2 of arrays of size 3 of arrays of size 4 of int`.
`*a` has the type `array of size 3 of arrays of size 4 of int`.
`**a` has the type `array of size 4 of int`.

All three arrays when decayed to corresponding pointers have the same value because they point to the same location in memory.

Comment: One way of simplifying it. `a, *a, **a, ***a` was the equivalent to writing `a, a[0], a[0][0], a[0][0][0]`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following Code:

```
int main()
{
    int a[2][3][4]={
            {
                {1,2,3,4},
                {4,5,6,7},
                {9,1,1,2}
            },
            {
                {2,1,4,7},
                {6,7,8,9},
                {0,0,0,0}
            }
            };

    printf("%u %u %u u%",a,*a,**a,***a);//how a == *a == **a print address 1002 please help me to understand ? 

}
```

The reason it was returning the address was because you didn't declare your 3d array properly at all. The above is the corrected code, try it out and let us know how it goes

Comment: The *inner* curly braces are optional if you specify the all of the initializers. OP is missing a comma after the 4, but otherwise there's nothing wrong with the OP's method of initializing the array.

Comment: @user3386109 There were only 2 errors that I saw to get the code to what I think the OP was trying to post. The missing comma after `1,2,3,4` and there is a typo in `printf`. At the end they print `u%` instead of `%u`

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're right. I'm going to edit the question, since those typos have nothing to do with the question.